# Conditional statement in AngularJS controller not working

Tags: angularjs

I am doing a simple conditional statement inside a controller function that gets called from a ng-click. The function **$scope.prevCor** works fine but when I add a conditional statement it stops working, the if part works but the else doesnt

```
app.controller('CorActivity', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://xxx-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/usercor/user/1').success(function(data) {
      $scope.cor = data[0].cor;


    });

    $scope.prevCor = function(data) {

        $http.get('http://xxx-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/prevusercor/user/'+data).success(function(data) {

          if($scope.userid)
          {

              $scope.userid = data[0].id;
          }
          else {
              $scope.userid = "None";
          }

        });      
    };    

  }]);
```

Comment: What do you expect to have in `userid` to reach else condition?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What are you doing, what do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: I am trying to change the {{userid}} if the data from the $http request is empty. So for example when a user clicks ng-click=prevCor(1), which is basically a previous page, then the {{userid}} value on the page should change to "None" since there is no user for that page / id

Comment: Now the else {  $scope.userid = "None"; } does not update {{userid}} as None

Comment: You're not testing "data from $http request". You're testing $scope.userid.